# Compress html website in htaccess apache server (mod_delflate not enabled) hosting server wont do it)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am having problems compressing my html website. 
I have spoken to my hosting company and asked if mod_gzip and/or Apache Module mod_deflate were enabled.
Their reply
They're not installed, no - as our hosting is designed around PHP, so we'd rather spend the CPU time executing that than compressing output.
I have also tried adding this at the top of my webpage and nothing happens

```
<?php
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
?>
```

I am not a programmer, but I do know how to edit .htaccess and web pages.

Could anybody advise the best way to compress my website to acheive a better loading time, I have used pagespeed and the compression seems to be a main factor. I've even thought about changing hosting companies.

Any much needed help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ob_start` can do it, but a more reliable way is to use a `php.ini` file. The file would include the following. This only works if `zlib` is enabled on the server, most have it.

```
; Enable GZIP compression at the default level
zlib.output_compression = On
zlib.output_compression_level = 6
```